# Functional programming in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, functional-programming, function-pointers

I have been reading this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer and am sort of confused. Since C/C++ support function pointers, doesn't that mean they support functional programming in general? Note that I don't actually want to use C or C++ for functional programming, but I'm curious since I have never heard that C or C++ supports such a thing. (I know that compilers for many functional programming languages exist in C, but that is not what I really mean by "support").

Comment: @cdbitesky, I think that's a little unfair.  The question is relatively precise in trying to ascertain the role of function pointers in permitting functional programming in general.  Obviously we can quibble a little about technical definitions of "functional programming", but I think I've addressed this in my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit:** I'm not sure why this answer gets so much hate. The question asks specifically about *function pointers*, and whether their presence means that C++ supports "functional programming in general".

In a sort of technical, not-very useful way:  yes*.  The real essence of "functional" programming is that functions are values.  C and C++ won't give you any help in terms of things like the easy creation and destruction of [lexical closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29), nor will it do you any favors in terms of [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).  The fact that you can simulate the appearance of functions behaving kinda like values using function pointers is really just a consequence of the equivalent expressivity languages.  Trying to conflate this with "functional programming" is really wading deep into the Turing tarpit.

*For a really technical distinction, C and C++ really don't have any function-typed *values*. A function pointer is distinct from a function value, even though they look kinda similar if you squint.

Comment: What about functors? They are the standard way of using the STL. In C++11 you have monomorphic lambdas, and in C++14 you have generic lambdas.

Comment: You can choose to interpret my answer as false for C++14.  The question was really about function pointers.

Answer (score 18):

Functional programming (please look it up if you're really interested) has little to do with functions pointers or lack of them.

C++ is a multi-paradigm language with a great deal of support for FP, especially the later versions. Many people working with WG21 like FP and push for support. In C++11 we even got lambda and in C++14 polymorphic lambdas debut. That covers many things. While functions stay second-class citizens lambda can take over fine.

Unfortunately tail-recursion handling is still not mandatory, but compilers actually handle it, and in the last decade even conveniently report "infinite recursion" when you just messed up the const overload. :)

You can go pretty far using FP style in C++, and learning it helps you make better code even when you chose other styles.  I encourage everyone to study [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/).

Comment: I'm actually trying to learn OCaml right now, which is what led to my exploring Wikipedia and coming across function pointers. I guess I jumped the gun by asking this question without really understanding what functional programming is yet.

Answer (score 4):

You can do functional programming in C++, although the language doesn't exactly help. First order functional programming, where you simply use immutable values as much as possible is certainly easy enough, and while not exactly easy, you can actually implement [monads](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2011/07/11/monads-in-c/)!